# VS Code всплывающие подсказки

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Недавно начал пользоваться редактором `VS Code` для разработки веб сайтов. Т.К. передо мной стоит задача написать и клиентскую (`front end`) и серверную (`back end`) часть, создаю файл `index.php` (С РАСШИРЕНИЕМ `php`). После этого, начинаю писать любой `html` код (например, тег `div`), но редактор начинает давать мне подсказки из `php`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественно меня такие подсказки не устраивают, я задался вопросом: а можно ли сделать так, чтобы `VS Code` определял, пишу я `html` или же `php` код, и давал верные подсказки.

Такая фишка есть в `sublime text 3`. Так например, если в `сублайме` начать писать текст `var_dump` в `html` коде, то никаких подсказок не появится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если обозначить теги `<?php` и `?>` и между этими тегами начать писать ту же функцию, то подсказки появятся:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следовательно, `сублайм` определяет что я сейчас пишу `php` и дает верные подсказки. Я погуглил, и нашел только вариант отключения **всех** подсказок в `VS Code`:

```
editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}
```

Теперь, собственно сами вопросы: как **отключить** автоподсказки для `html` кода (т.к. для этого у меня есть `Emmet`) и научить `VS Code` определять что я сейчас пишу php код и давать верные подсказки (т.е. когда я пишу `html` код, редактор должен просто молчать, а когда `php` код - подсказывать)... Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Спасибо!!!

Answer (score -1):

Знаю, что ответ поздний, но кому-то может это и пригодится.
Скорее всего могут помочь расширения [PHP IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zobo.php-intellisense) и/или [PHP Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode).